# Retrieve collection using limit and offset in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, query

I want to retrieve magento 2 model collection using limit offset, like raw query like this:

```
$rawQuery = SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id = '".$test_id."' and status = '1' LIMIT 600 OFFSET ".$offset;
```

i have tried using this,but not working,

```
    $collections = $model->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('test_id',array('eq'=>$test_id))
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>'1'))
    ->setLimit(600)->setOffset($offset);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$collection->setPageSize(600)` and `$collection->setCurPage($offset)` methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can set limit and offset like this,

> $collectionLimit = 600;
>
> $collectionOffset = $offset;

```
$collections = $model->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('test_id',array('eq'=>$test_id))
->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>'1'));

$collections->getSelect()->limit($collectionLimit, $collectionOffset);
```

Comment: when i use foreach for $collections, it retrieve empty data

Comment: is this work with pagination for custom collection?